# What do you call the science of determining the location of a geographical feature from pictures?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the science of determining the location of a geographical feature from pictures? By that any geographical features, or for that matter any element shown in pictures? I know some mathematical formulas allow you to do that, but I don't know the name of the discipline.

Comment: What do you call it? Is there a word in your languages? Have you used a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term that may fit what you describe is [photogrammetry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry).

Hee are some other, more specific terms that may be related:

- [Automatic target recognition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_target_recognition)
- [Image registration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration)
- [Geodesy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy)
- [Content-based image retrieval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval)